# Variables entre clases en Flutter

Tags: flutter, class

lo que pasa es que cree una clase que son dos botones y un texto que sera el contador
tiene dos variables miembro y una es contador que es el que me interesa consultar desde otra clase pero siempre me da el valor por defecto 0
lo intento retornar pero no funciona y al llamarlo sin () me retorna Closure: () => dynamic from Function 'val' y con () me retorna el 0

```
class Danos extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  int value;
  int val() {
    print(createState().val());
    return this.value = createState().val();
  }

  String n;
  Danos([this.n = "nombre", this.value = 0]);
  _DanosState createState() => _DanosState(this.n);
}

class _DanosState extends State<Danos> {
  int value;
  String n;

  _DanosState([this.n = "nombre"]);
  int val() {
    return this.value;
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    value = widget.value;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .06,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .58,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            //width: ,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .05,
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: less,
              heroTag: "Menos" + this.n,
              tooltip: 'Menos' + this.n,
              child: Icon(Icons.exposure_neg_1),
            ),
          ),
          Text(n + "=" + (this.value.toString())),
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .05,
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: add,
              heroTag: "Mas" + this.n,
              tooltip: 'Mas' + this.n,
              child: Icon(Icons.plus_one),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  add() {
    setState(() {
      this.value += 1;
    });
  }

  less() {
    setState(() {
      (this.value > 0) ? this.value -= 1 : this.value = 0;
    });
  }
}
```

Esto es en la misma pantalla no cambio de pantalla solo que se creo la clase porque se ocupan muchos widget asi

Comment: te recomiendo leer este post que escribí https://medium.com/comunidad-flutter/comunicaci%C3%B3n-entre-widgets-5f61b6c2e56c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta subir el Estado a un widget pariente.

Es lo que sugieren en la documentación

Estado de elevación

En Flutter, tiene sentido mantener el estado por encima de los widgets que lo utilizan.

Por qué? En frameworks declarativos como Flutter, si quieres cambiar la interfaz de usuario, tienes que reconstruirla. No hay una manera fácil de tener MyCart.updateWith(somethingNew). En otras palabras, es difícil cambiar imperativamente un widget desde fuera, llamando a un método en él. E incluso si pudieras hacer que esto funcione, estarías luchando contra el framework en lugar de dejar que te ayud

Comment: hola mira un pregunta es que tengo mi widget principal donde realizo varias instancias de la clase para formar un menu y tengo otras cajas de texto
De estos objetos quiero obtener el valro de la variable Value ya que en el widget principal tengo un método donde se conectana a mi sevidor para guardar en bd 
Tienes alguna idea de como hacer esta parte? por que siempre me da el valor con el que se por defecto o el valor que le mando nunca el aumento

Comment: Intenta utilizar el paquete de Provider, aquí te mando el link. https://pub.dev/packages/provider 

Y la página principal de Flutter tiene una instrucciones de cómo aprender a usarlo, https://flutter-es.io/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple